# $1234x+567y=89$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I need to solve this with congruence. What I already done is :
$$1234x+567y=89$$
$$1234x\equiv 89\bmod 567$$
$$1234\cdot17x\equiv 89\cdot17\bmod 567$$
$$20978x\equiv 1513\bmod 567$$
$$x\equiv -1513\bmod 567$$
$x_0=-1513$, so $x=-1513+567t$
Now I'm stuck here. I don't know how to search for $y_0$

Edit :
I found out I can change the equation into $567y\equiv 89\bmod 1234$
$$567y\equiv 89\bmod 1234$$
$$567\cdot 37y\equiv 89\cdot 37\bmod 1234$$
$$20979y\equiv 3293\bmod 1234$$
$$y\equiv 3293\bmod 1234$$
So $y_0=3293$ and $y=3293+1234t$

Did I get something wrong? Do I need to do more than this?

Comment: Typo? 5679 or 567y ?

Comment: Ah yes. It's $567y$.

Comment: Congruence alone is not enough. By Bezout, $1234\cdot(-17)+567\cdot(37)=1$. Multiplying by $89$ we obtain a solution.

Comment: Yes, but I want to search the answer with another way. I read somewhere that I can use only the congruence, but it isn't very clear on how to find $y_0$

Comment: $\!\bmod 567\!:\ \color{#c00}x\equiv -1513\equiv \color{#c00}{188}\,$ has corresponding  $\ y  = (89-1234\,\color{#c00}x)/567 = -409\ \ $

Comment: @DietrichBurde What *precisely* do you mean by the vague claim that "congruence alone is not enough"?

Comment: @DietrichBurde But what do *you* mean? I can certainly solve it "with congruences".

Comment: @BillDubuque I meant, not only considering the term modulo $n$. We actually have to find a modular inverse.

Comment: @DietrichBurde But modular inversion is usually considered part of congruence arithmetic.  I suspect that "with congruence" is simply meant to distinguish from other (equivalent) methods that avoid the use of congruence language (e.g. some forms of the extended Euclidean algorithm, or continued fractions, etc).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have already solved the equation. Simply plug in $y$ and $x$ into your original equation and then solve for $t$ in the equation below:

$$1234x+567y=1234(-1513+567t)+567(3293+1234t)=89$$

It seems that $t=0$ is a solution. Which means $x=-1513$ and $y=3293$ are solutions to this equation.

Comment: If you change the sign of $1234t$, you get the formula for all solutions: one for each integer $t$.

Comment: Why is that true? and how do we justify flipping the sign? @FabioSomenzi

Comment: If you keep the sign as it is, the only solution is trivially $t=0$, and the exercise of adding the extra terms is futile.  With the flipped sign, you start with $1234 (-1513) + 567 (3293) = 89$, which is obviously true, and you add and subtract $1234 \cdot 567 \cdot t$, which does not change the value of the left-hand side.  Try a few values of $t$ and you can see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have $100x\equiv89\pmod{567}$ and some calculation gives $x=188+567t$ Taking $t=0$ we get $y=\dfrac{89-1234\cdot188}{567}=-409$ and the general solution can be given as $$x=188+567t\\y=-409-1234t$$ which comes from
$$1234x+567y=89\\1234\cdot188+567\cdot(-409)=89$$ making a  difference giving $1234(x-x_0)-567(y-y_0)=0$ thus....

Comment: As written, your answer suggests that, taking $t=1$, $x=188+567$ and $y=-409+1234$ is a solution to $1234x + 567y = 89$.

Comment: @Favio Somenzi: Thank you. I had put the positive sign where the negative sign should be. I already corrected. Thanks again. (It is very commendable your attitude of not putting a downvote as more than one would have put it without considering that it was a simple slip)